# Type Mismatch during a Calculation of a Range in Vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sorry if this is posted some where else, but I have searched around a lot and apparently type mismatch is a common error that appears with anything.
I am using Vba to clean a copy of a Csv file. This is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CleanCopy()
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rMerge As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim dCell As Range
Dim iRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Reservas")

iRow = ws.Cells.find(What:="*", _
                 SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                 LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

If ws.Range("A1") = "Status" Then
   If rMerge Is Nothing Then
     Set rMerge = ws.Range("A1").MergeArea.EntireColumn
   End If
Else
  MsgBox ("Copiou de forma errada, tente novamente")
  Exit Sub
End If

rMerge.Delete
Set rCell = Nothing
Set rMerge = Nothing

If ws.Range("D1") = "Adults / " Then
  ws.Range("D1") = Left(ws.Range("D1"), 6)
  Else
    MsgBox ("Copiou de forma errada, tente novamente")
    Exit Sub
  End If

If ws.Range("H1") <> "Total" Then
    MsgBox ("Copiou de forma errada, tente novamente")
    Exit Sub
End If


For Each rCell In ws.UsedRange
  If rCell.Row > 3 Then
    If rCell.MergeCells Then
        If rMerge Is Nothing Then
            Set rMerge = rCell.MergeArea.EntireRow
        Else
            Set rMerge = Union(rMerge, rCell.MergeArea.EntireRow)
        End If
    End If
  End If
Next


rMerge.Delete
Set rCell = Nothing
Set rMerge = Nothing

Range("D2:D3").Select
  Selection.ClearContents
  Range("D1:D3").Select
  With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
  End With
  Selection.merge

Set Rng = ws.Range("D4:D700")
Rng.Replace What:="~/", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
  :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
For Each dCell In Rng
  dCell.Value = Left(dCell, 1)
Next

i = 4
With ws
  While i < iRow
    .Cells(i, "H") = .Cells(i, "H") - .Cells(i, "D")
    i = i + 1
  Wend
End With

End Sub
```

So I get type mismatch right at the end when I try to recalculate the H column:

```
  .Cells(i, "H") = .Cells(i, "H")) - (.Cells(i, "D")
```

I tried putting CDbl on them and when I do the "left" code but that doesn't work either. I know I am overlooking something, so I would appreciate if you can tell me what it is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the values of those cells when it fails?

Comment: To reiterate: **What are the values of those cells when it fails?** If they are text or errors you will get a Type Mismatch.

Comment: Consider adding an if-else-end clause to test whether values are isnumeric(). Debug.print their value if not numeric. Or put on error resume next, then click options, break on all errors. See if that helps you identify which value(s) is behaving unexpectedly. Best to execute 'on error goto 0'and remove 'on error resume next' once done

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. H column is only numbers. D column is being generated as you can see by the code. It only takes the first digit of the D column which is a number. I will try the last recommendation to test the numeric value now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys, I like to thank you all. unfortunately I am not able yet to give the "useful comments" thing yet or I would as you were all very helpful.
What helped me the most was the isnumeric bit which helped me find out that the whole h column was appearing as text even though there are only numbers in that column. In case you are wondering, in the end this is what my while code looks like and I put some extra variables just in case to make the subtraction comes out as double:

```
With ws
  While .Cells(i, "A") <> ""
    TT = CDbl(.Cells(i, "D"))

    'This is just in case there is any issues with decimal parts
    sVal = Replace(.Cells(i, "H"), ".", ",")
        If Not sVal = "" Then
            If IsNumeric(sVal) = True Then
            Total = CDbl(sVal)
            End If
        End If

    .Cells(i, "H").Value = Total - TT
    i = i + 1
  Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to subtract a range from a range. Type mismatch means you are trying to use a variable of a wrong type for the operation.

Try something like:

```
.Cells(i, "H").Value = .Cells(i, "H").Value - .Cells(i, "D").Value
```

Comment: `.Cells(i, "H") = .Cells(i, "H") - .Cells(i, "D")` will make use of the `Range` object's default property, and is thus equivalent to `.Cells(i, "H").Value = .Cells(i, "H").Value - .Cells(i, "D").Value`.  So the first part of the answer is probably true, but the "Try something like" part won't achieve anything.

Comment: That is not the case in Excel 2013 AFAIK.

Comment: I use MS Pro Plus 2013, and it is true in that version.  (And AFAIK it was true as long ago as I can remember [which, admittedly, these days probably means "it was true last week"] and it is true in Excel 2016.)

Comment: You're right - I just tested that. I think I'm confusing that with a different issue between MS2007 and MS2013 code migrations.

Comment: FWIW - I always prefer people to explicitly use the `.Value`, because it avoids potential problems when some operation will accept either an object **or** a value, but I just didn't want the OP to waste time in this case testing something that wasn't going to help (because the `-` operator won't accept an actual `Range` object as either of its operands, and therefore will cause the `Value` property to be accessed instead).

Answer (score 0):

Are the values in columns H and D not numbers, maybe? You might be trying to subtract text from numbers, which wouldn't make sense.

Edit: It must be that you have data in column D that isn't numeric.

```
Set Rng = ws.Range("D4:D700")
Rng.Replace What:="~/", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
  :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
For Each dCell In Rng
  dCell.Value = Left(dCell, 1)
Next
```

This is the section of code that you need to look at. I suspect that it isn't returning all numeric characters in cell D.

Comment: H column is all numbers and D column is in the code, being using the "left" formula to extract the first digit of a number

Comment: Ahhhh! I know what the issue is. The Left function is making it all text in column D. I've edited my response for an idea on how to fix this issue.

Comment: The expression `10 - "2"` will be handled without issues by VBA, returning the number `8`.  So, as long as column D is numeric, there isn't any issues whether it is a number stored as text or (more likely in this case) just a number.  (If you do something like `Cells(1,"D").Value = Left("5ad", 1)`, Excel will place the **number** `5` into the cell, not the string `"5"`.  It "guesses" that you want a numeric value in the cell, and you have to explicitly do something like `Cells(1,"D").Value = "'" & Left("5ad", 1)` if you want to store the string `"5"` into the cell.)

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. He must have data in column D that isn't numeric then. An accidental "8-" or something like that. I feel like we might not be able to help on this without seeing the data.

Comment: If you see my answer in the bottom it was H column that was coming as text and not D. D was fine. Some kind of weird decoding stuff when the csv was transferred to excel. solved it with some Cdbl's. but thanks